# bootstrap type ahead spring mvc

Tags: jquery, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I am learning bootstrap and spring mvc, i have begun learning some time back only. I am trying to implement a typeahead in bootstrap3. I am following this example 
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=typeahead-with-local-dataset

but it doesn't work on my machine. I have implemented a spring mvc, such that when a user clicks a link, the hyperlink takes it to a page called QueryBoard.html, which is intercepted by my controller and it fetches some list of strings from db and passes as the model to the page, i have not yet implemented how to display the list on frontend jsp page,

Before that, I was experimenting with simple typeahead example but it doesn't work. Below is my code. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Twitter Typeahead</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="/resources/core/js/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
            name: 'accounts',
            local: ['Audi', 'BMW', 'Bugatti', 'Ferrari', 'Ford', 'Lamborghini', 'Mercedes Benz', 'Porsche', 'Rolls-Royce', 'Volkswagen']
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        font-family: sans-serif;
        position: relative;
        margin: 100px;
    }
    .typeahead, .tt-query, .tt-hint {
        border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
        border-radius: 8px;
        font-size: 24px;
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        outline: medium none;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        width: 396px;
    }
    .typeahead {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .typeahead:focus {
        border: 2px solid #0097CF;
    }
    .tt-query {
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
    }
    .tt-hint {
        color: #999999;
    }
    .tt-dropdown-menu {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        border-radius: 8px;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        margin-top: 12px;
        padding: 8px 0;
        width: 422px;
    }
    .tt-suggestion {
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 24px;
        padding: 3px 20px;
    }
    .tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor {
        background-color: #0097CF;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .tt-suggestion p {
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```

```
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <h2>Type your favorite car name</h2>
<input type="text" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off"    spellcheck="false">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: i was expecting that when i type a letter 'A' it would show the list of cars starting with 'A'. I tried running in intellij debug mode, the function is called on page load not when i click on the text field

Comment: Are you sure `/resources/core/js/typeahead.bundle.min.js` is loaded in your browser?

Comment: my bad using wrong js :(